# How to automate the renaming of a txt file using python

Tags: python, file

I am trying to find a way to automate the renaming of a file using python.

So the text files need to be renamed everyday to include yesterday's date (T-1).

For example: `FileName_20200121.txt` needs to be renamed to `FileName_20200120.txt`.

How do I go about this?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You will probably find what you need in the [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html) library

Answer (score 0):

This script will search for a date in format `"%Y%m%d"` in your file name (for example `"FileName_20200121_foobar.txt"` will work) and replace the date found in file by `date - 1day`

```
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

old_filename = "FileName_20200121.txt"

strTime = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")
split_str = old_filename.split(".")[0].split("_")
format_str = "%Y%m%d"

for s in split_str:
    try:
        old_date_str = s # 20200121
        old_date = datetime.strptime(s, format_str).date() # 2020-01-21
        new_date = old_date - timedelta(days=1) # 2020-01-20
        new_date_str = new_date.strftime(format_str) # 20200120
    except:
        pass

new_filename = old_filename.replace(old_date_str, new_date_str)
print("new_filename", new_filename)
# FileName_20200120.txt

os.rename(old_filename, new_filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`os.rename(src, dst)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename):

> Rename the file or directory `src` to `dst`. If `dst` exists, the operation
>   will fail with an `OSError`

The following should do the trick, assuming that all of your files end in `.txt`:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


directory = '/path/to/files'
filenames = [f for f in os.listdir(directory) if f.endswith('.txt')]
yesterday = datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(1), '%Y%m%d')

for file_name in filenames:
    new_file_name = file_name[:-12] + yesterday + file_name[-4:]
    os.rename(os.path.join(directory, file_name), os.path.join(directory, new_file_name))
```

Comment: The folder will be storing quite a few text files, so is there a function I can use similar to "f.endswith('.txt')", like maybe "f.startswith('FileName')"? Thanks for the help

Comment: Yeap, you can use `f.startswith('')`. Use any condition that does the trick for your use case. I assume the above is generic enough  :)

Comment: Is it possible to use both **f.endswith(' ')** and **f.startswith(' ')** on the line `filenames = [f for f in os.listdir(directory) if f.endswith('.txt')]`?

Comment: Yes. Use `filenames = [f for f in os.listdir(directory) if f.endswith('.txt') and f.startswith('whatever you want')]`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [`os.rename`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.rename)

but the files need to exist and you must know their complete path and name

make sure to run `os.path.exists(filename)` first just to prevent any errors from coming

for changing the dates you can use the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module

and you can configure Windows settings to have the script run everyday by

pressing Windows+R, then type `shell:startup`.

and adding the file in the startup folder (or make a batch file that runs the python script)

or you can go to scheduled tasks to do that.